# Getting image from database using spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I got a database with a column of format bytes where I store an encoded image
I use this code to encode it :

```
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());
String base64String = encodeByteArrayToBase64(fileContent);
```

I simply define endpoint :

```
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public Host get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return hostRepository.getReferenceById(id);
    }
```

When accessing endpoint with all data from this object I get other values that are stored in database. For example data in db looks like :

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAIAAADTED8xAAAgAElEQVR4nOy9ebNkx3EvlktVnaW77zYzAAlgsHAR8QiSomR5kRUvFIr3pfwt/C30t8MOv78ctkN+si1LTxJ ...
```

and what i get in postman is :

```
"hostPhoto": "aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQVFBQUFBRUFDQUlBQUFEVEVEOHhBQUFnQUVsRVFWUjRuT3k5ZWJOa3gzRXZsa3RWbmFXNzd6WXpBQWxnc0hBUjhRaVNvbVI1a1JVdkZJcjNwZnd0L0MzMHQ4TU92NzhjdGtOK3NpMUxUeEpKMGR4QURqREF6TnladS9SNnRxcktUUDl4K3Q3YkY1Z21BWk1nQnlBeVlpWjZlczZwYy9xY3pLck1YLzR5Qy8vNy8rNC93aDlFakQ3ZDhhalBId2FlUHc3YTg0Y2h4Tjk4S2JvWjgvbFhoVDFYL1d5 ...
```

There is some discrepancy with data which I cannot understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first text (starting with `iVBORw0KGgo`) is a PNG file, encoded in base 64. Try it here - https://www.base64decode.org/. The second text (starting with `aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQU`) is the first text, but base64 encoded again. My guess is that you encoded instead of decoded it. The expected result will be binary and you won't get a pretty string out of it. If the result starts with `PNG` you have found the magic bytes and you are good to go.